# If $ \prod_{k=0}^n (x+\frac{1}{2^k}) = \sum_{k=0} ^n a_kx^k $find $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-4}} = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

If $$ \prod_{k=1}^n (x+\frac{1}{2^k}) = \sum_{k=0} ^n a_kx^k 
$$then find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-4}} = ?$$

I’m able to find $a_{n-2}$ easily but finding $a_{n-4}$ is quite difficult for me. I think involving binomial theorem or principle of inclusion and exclusion may work but still I’m not able to proceed with that.

Comment: could you write your tries (and successes). Binomial should work (or at least give you sufficient intuition) Try doing so on examples where n=4 or n=5. Derivation in 0 could also work

Comment: The LHS has degree $n+1$, but the RHS has degree $n$.

Comment: Sorry for that, now fixed the error.

Comment: Is the limit to be when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ instead of $x\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: Fixed that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler to recast this problem in terms of the function$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{1+x} = g(x/2),\quad\text{where}\quad g(x)\doteq\prod_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x}{2^k}\right).
$$
The quantity you seek is the ratio of the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^4$ in the power-series expansion of $f(x)$.  But$$
f(x) = (-x/2;1/2)_\infty,
$$
where $$
(a;q)_n \doteq \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-a q^k)
$$ denotes the $q$-Pochhammer symbol.  Using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#Identities) $$
(x;q)_\infty = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n q^{n(n-1)/2}}{(q;q)_n} x^n,
$$
we find that the power-series expansion of $f(x)$ is
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n(n-1)/2} }{(1/2;1/2)_n} 2^{-n} x^n.
$$
From the definition of $(a;q)_n$, we observe that $$
(1/2;1/2)_n = \frac{\alpha_n}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}
$$
where $$
\alpha_n \doteq \prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1)
$$ is sequence [A005329](https://oeis.org/A005329) in OEIS, with values of $1$, $1$, $3$, $21$, and $315$ for $n = 0$ to $4$.  Substituting this into the above expansion for $f(x)$, we see that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\alpha_n} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^3}{3 \cdot 7} + \frac{x^4}{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 15} + \cdots.
$$
Therefore the desired ratio is $(1/3) / (1/(3\cdot 7 \cdot 15)) = 7\cdot 15 = 105$.

**Edit:**  The OP asked for a more elementary demonstration.

The first step is to realize that the way the problem is stated makes things artificially difficult by referencing coefficients whose indices are going to $\infty$.  Therefore we divide each side of the original equation by $x^n$, substitute $1/x$ for $x$, and let $n \rightarrow \infty$ to arrive at the expression
$$
f(x) \doteq \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x}{2^k}\right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n. 
$$
Then the desired limit is $c_2/c_4$.  Make sure you understand this transformation into a question about $f(x)$ before proceeding.

Now we need a formula for $c_n$. Trivially $c_0 = 1$.  To find the other $c_n$ we use the identity $$
(1+x) f(x) = f(2x).
$$
That is, multiplying $f(x)$ by $(1+x)$ is the same as changing the definition of $f(x)$ to begin with $k=0$.  However, computing $f(2x)$ results in the same expression as $(1+x)f(x)$:  we just have to relabel the indices by shifting $k$ by $1$.  Make sure you understand how to prove the above identity before proceeding.

To find the coefficients $c_n$, we expand the identity above as
$$
(1 + x) (c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots) = c_0 + 2 c_1 x + 4 c_2 x^2 + \cdots.
$$
Equating coefficients of $x$ in this expression yields the equalities $$
\begin{align}
c_0 &= c_0,\\
c_0 + c_1 &= 2 c_1, \\
c_1 + c_2 &= 4 c_2, \\
c_2 + c_3 &= 8 c_3, \\
&\text{etc.}
\end{align}
$$
Simplifying these equations, we find that $$
c_n = \frac{c_{n-1}}{2^n-1},
$$
which, in conjunction with the initial value $c_0 = 1$, yields the required formula for the coefficients $c_n$.

Comment: I’m not aware about q-Pochhammer symbol, still I read about it and then tried to understand the answer but couldn’t. Can you please provide an approach within jee syllabus?

Comment: Added more elementary solution.

Comment: Wonderful explanation!